# How to solve the issue "AH00169: caught SIGTERM" shutting down in Apache when running WordPress

Tags: apache-httpd, wordpress

Environment: debian9+LAMP+wordpress4.9.3, build on my local PC, and used myself.

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Mon Feb 05 09:42:09.965635 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1083] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 05 09:42:09.965658 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1083] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Feb 05 14:41:47.057389 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1083] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

So many AH00169 and AH00163 and some AH00094 are in the error log.
For every day there is almost 40 lines of error information.

It is used by one person, me!

Check all configure with apachectl.

```
sudo apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Some of the important configuration files:

1. File `000-default.conf`

   ```
   cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. File `apache2.conf`

   ```
   cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
   PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
   Timeout 300
   KeepAlive On
   MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
   KeepAliveTimeout 5
   User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
   Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
   HostnameLookups Off
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   LogLevel warn
   IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
   IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
   Include ports.conf
   <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all denied
   </Directory>
   <Directory /usr/share>
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   AccessFileName .htaccess
   <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
       Require all denied
   </FilesMatch>
   LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
   LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
   LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
   IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
   IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
   ```
3. File "ports.conf"

   ```
   cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf
   Listen 80
   <IfModule ssl_module>
       Listen 443
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
       Listen 443
   </IfModule>
   ```

[image: M0DD9.png]

From `Mon Feb 05 15` till `Mon Feb 05 16`, not how much error info there is!
It restarts automatically.

I have used WordPress for about three years, and there are only 1500 articles on my WordPress-based site. There is just one user - me, not open on the Internet.

Nowadays there are often an issue such as below.

[image: 2v9Pu.png]

Comment: How is your Apache started?  When this happens, does Apache restart automatically?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable apache2` make it automatically run at boot.

Comment: I use my wordpress ----write some article ,edit and delete,had not shutdowned apache myself manually.

Comment: Does it restart automatically?   How often does this happen?

Comment: Sure that it restart automatically for about 2 times per hour.

Comment: Every 15'??  Can you check how often logrotate is running?

Comment: [Mon Feb 05 09:42:09.965658 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1083] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Feb 05 14:41:47.057389 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1083] AH00169: caught SIGTERM,  That is 5 hours in between.

Comment: Please watch the attatchment.

Comment: Done.  Almost no restarts during the night.  Is there any relation between the restarts and the publishing of new articles?

Comment: Saving has been disabled until you're reconnected.We're backing up this post in your browser,just in case.

Comment: Is that meant as an answer to my question?

Comment: Why?Which result in the issue "apache2 restarting over and over"?What is the matter with my browser ?

Comment: Is there any relation between the restarts and the publishing of new articles?

Comment: When `connetction lost `happen, there is a apache's restart ,why?

Comment: Of course you lose your connection when Apache restarts.  But that is not my question.  I'm asking you if this happens when you publish a new article or when you change an existing article.

Comment: Have you looked at the resources available on the server? Memory and storage? Also is this wordpress site accessible via the internet? have you tried to disable all the sites and testing it that way? My guess is that your system is running our of memory and killing the processes.